# What's the right syntax for specifying a local extras_require in a setup.py?

Tags: setup.py

I am trying to install an optional extra package in my setup.py

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my_package",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        # Your normal dependencies here
    ],
    extras_require={
        'extra': ["my_local_package @ file:my_local_package"]
    }
)
```

After `pip install -e ".["extra"]"` I get this error:

```
error in my_package setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/swartchris8/experiment_with_extra_package) with minimal code